# Ajax request doesn't execute (totally ghost)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I use PHP, jQuery together for make an application with a database, I am new using jQuery and ajax, I wanted to use ajax to do UPDATE of my database without have to refresh. For the jQuery code I took this video as example :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kcka5WBMktw

I tested my php by classical form and post method : it's working 
I tried to add alert() in jQuery for debug, alert sent me back the expected values.

I open the console with network : nothing appear concerning my AJAX request.

Here my jQuery :

```
$('.ButtonEdit').on('click', function() {
    let id = $(this).attr('id');
    let name = $('#name'+id).val();
    alert('click');
    req = $.ajax({
        url: "menu.php?Option=updateIgr",
        type : 'POST',
        data : { name : name, code : code }
    });
});
```

here my php that I want to launch with Ajax :

```
 case "updateIgr":
     require("Class/Ingredient.php");
     require("Class/IngredientsManager.php");
     $data = array ('code' => $_POST['code'],'name' => $_POST['name']);
     $updaterIngredient = new IngredientsManager;
     $updatedIngredient = $updaterIngredient->update(new Ingredient($data));
     break;
```

I expected than it will update my page in live without have to refresh and the actual result is : nothing, actually nothing happen. Is it something special to install or setting up ? I turn in circle on research, thank you for your help

Comment: Your Ajax request just sends information to server and does nothing more. You need to manually re-render elements inside HTML. Check `success` method of Ajax.

Comment: Its a bad practice to use `alert('something')` for debugging, it stops the latter code from execution until you click ok try `console.log('click')`. Also add .success(), .done() as per docs http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code variable is not declared

```
$('.ButtonEdit').on('click', function() {
    let id = $(this).attr('id');
    let code = $(this).attr('id');// please assign your code here
    let name = $('#name'+id).val();
    alert('click');
    req = $.ajax({
        url: "menu.php?Option=updateIgr",
        type : 'POST',
        data : { name : name, code : code }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have success and failure handlers for the Ajax request.

```
$('.ButtonEdit').on('click', function() {
  let id = $(this).attr('id');
  let name = $('#name'+id).val();

  req = $.ajax({
    url: "menu.php?Option=updateIgr",
    type : 'POST',
    data : { name : name, code : code }
  });

  // Callback handler that will be called on success
  req.done(function (response, status, jqXHR){
    // Log a message to the console
    console.log("It worked!");
  });

  // Callback handler that will be called on failure
  req.fail(function (jqXHR, status, err){
    // Log the error to the console
    console.error("An error occurred: " + status, err);
  });

});
```

You will need to update the handlers to suit your needs.

Comment: is it reliable to do alert.error ("The data haven't been updated, the following error occured :" + statut, err) for stop the latter code from execution until the user click ok

Comment: `alert.error()` is not a function. The correct method is `window.alert()` - See the [Window.alert() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert). The popup dialog is not considered a good user experience so you might want to consider using a jQuery notification message plugin instead.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest check this code.

$('.ButtonEdit').click(function() { var id = $(this).attr('id'); var name = $('#name'+id).val(); $ajax({ url: "menu.php?Option=updateIgr", type : 'POST', data : { name : name, id : id } }); });